# Using flutter_map, how to reload map on Pinch Zoom In/Out?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, setstate, mobile-development

I am using the package **[flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map)** to build a map in my app, where there are circles around points. I am trying to turn this layer on/off dynamically, in accordance to the zoom level.

Such as the following, where I'm trying to only show the CircleLayerOptions layer if the map zoom level is >14 (zoomed in).

```
FlutterMap(
      mapController: _mapController,
      options: MapOptions(
        center: LatLng(startLat, startLon),
        zoom: 14,
        plugins: [MarkerClusterPlugin()],
        onTap: (_, __) => _popupController.hideAllPopups(),
      ),
      layers: [
        TileLayerOptions(
          minZoom: 1,
          maxZoom: 20,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ),
        // HERE (show circles around the points if zoomed in enough) <---------------------
        (_mapController.zoom > 14) ? CircleLayerOptions(circles: myCircles)
                                   : Container(),
        ]
);
```

The issue with this is that **pinch zoom specifically** doesn't reload the map at all.

**Any idea how I can reload the state of the map automatically when the
user pinch zooms in or out?**

(*In case anyone asks, I am not using google maps as I'm trying to keep my app open source*)

Comment: this is because you have to rebuild your `FlutterMap` widget when you zoom in/out to specific level (there is a `Stream` in `MapController` that you can listen to find out the current zoom)

Comment: Could you show me an example of how this would work? I am pretty new to flutter_maps and the MapController

Comment: `_mapController.mapEventStream.listen((event) => print(event))` if you call this do you see any zoom events?

Comment: I do! I'm also able to get the current `_mapController.zoom` as well, which is helpful. However, how do I use this to my advantage to reload the map layers? Should I put the `FlutterMap()` inside the event listener..?

Comment: so now, instead of `print(event)` you should add the code that checks if the zoom is at your desired level and simply call `setState` to rebuild `FlutterMap`

Comment: Oh I see perfect! I'm always hesitant to call a `setState(() {})` purely for a reload (I get into reload loops often), but this worked great. The event listener monitors the zoom, and based on that I can reload the map when I want. If you answer the question formally instead of these comments I'll mark yours as the correct answer!

Comment: great, but I'm too lazy, feel free to write a self answer then :-)

Comment: Oh ok haha, I more meant to give you the Stack Overflow points and credit, but I'm happy to write one as well! :)

Comment: It's ok if you do that

Comment: btw, i just found that you can also use this: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_map/latest/flutter_map/MapOptions/onMapEvent.html - it should work the same way as `_mapController.mapEventStream.listen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*****SOLUTION*****:
*Courtesy of pskink (see above)*

The `MapController` has an event listener that allows me to capture when pinch zoom is being done (called `Drag` as the event name). I can then call `setState(() {})` to reload the map as I please. See below.

```
    _mapController.mapEventStream.listen((event) {
      if (_mapController.zoom >= 12) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    });

    return FlutterMap(
      mapController: _mapController,
      ... etc ...
    );
```

Comment: one note: i am assuming that it is some simplified version of your code, in practice your `if` should be more complex to prevent the situation when your keep zooming in, I mean the case when it's 12.25, 12.5, 13 etc, in that case you will call multiple extra `setState` that will only downgrade the app performance

Comment: and the easiest way is to use `final zoomNotifier = ValueNotifier(false)` then `zoomNotifier.addListener(setState)` and finally `_mapController.mapEventStream.listen((event) => zoomNotifier.value = _mapController.zoom >= 12);` you can check it out by adding some `print(_mapController.zoom)` statement inside your `build` method

Comment: Yes I should've clarified that! I appreciate the follow-up. I implemented a bool to inform the `setState(() {})` call so that it only triggered a rebuild if the circles needed to be turned on/off, to limit the performance going into reloads.